# Can IPython console be interactive in Eclipse/Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, ipython, pydev

I use Eclipse(version Neon 3 (4.6.3))to learn Python code. Is there anyway to make IPython Console opened in Eclipse Neon/PyDev? Please note that I already tried the PyDev Console but it doesn't work. For example, I tested a function in the PyDev Console, it gave me the error:
File "", line 1, in
I don't understand the message.  Can anyone please help!  Thank you!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interactive console in PyDev will use the IPython console by default if you have it installed.

You can start with with `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` and send contents from an open editor line by line to the console with `F2`.

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for more details on the interactive console.

Comment: Hello Fabio, when I used Ctrl + Alt + Enter, the code sent to Python console.  With this console, it works like an independent editor, not interacts with the eclipse editor.  When I execute the code from eclipse editor, the output shown in a console, which is not either IPython or Python.  I have installed Anaconda package in my computer (window 10, 64-bit).  I know that IPython is also included in the package.  I don't know how to make a path so that I can interact the python code between the eclipse editor and the Ipython console.  If any advice, I really appreciate it! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Actually it is not default anymore. According to changelog you need to add IPYTHONENABLE=TRUE in the environment (which I do not know how to do/doesnt work for me)